# mongoose aggregate : how to count matching documents and insert counting using Promises

Tags: node.js, mongoose, aggregation-framework

When I perform the following aggregate

```
return this.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'groups',
      localField: '_group',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'group'
    }
  },
  { $match: query },
  {
    $project: {
      group: {
        $let:{
          vars:{
            firstGroup:{
              $arrayElemAt:["$group",0]
            }
          },
          in:{
            name:"$$firstGroup.name",
            description:"$$firstGroup.description"
          }
        }
      },
      name: 1,
      description: 1,
      _id: 0
    }
  },
  { $sort: sortBy },
  { $limit: resultsPerPage },
  { $skip: skipDocuments }
])
```

with  query = {} 
no limit no skip
I get 8 matching roles grouped by group.name

```
ROLES: [
{"name":"NewRole","description":"NewRole description","group":{}},{"name":"Visitor","description":"no permissions","group":{}},
{"name":"NewRoleInGroup","description":"NewRoleInGroup description","group":{"name":"GroupA","description":"Description GroupA"}},
{"name":"admin","description":"can RW group, user","group":{"name":"GroupA","description":"Description GroupA"}},
{"name":"employee","description":"can R group, can read user","group":{"name":"GroupA","description":"Description GroupA"}},
{"name":"manager","description":"can R group, can RW user","group":{"name":"GroupA","description":"Description GroupA"}},
{"name":"employee","description":"can R group, can read user","group":{"name":"GroupB","description":"Description GroupB"}},
{"name":"manager","description":"can R group, can RW user","group":{"name":"GroupB","description":"Description GroupB"}},
{"name":"employee","description":"can R group, can read user","group":{"name":"GroupC","description":"Description GroupC"}}
]
```

Now  I would like to insert the total matching documents as the first object in the result to get track of it (when a limit is specified in the aggregate, I should return the total number of docs)

```
ROLES: [
{"roleCount": 8},
{"name":"NewRole","description":"NewRole description","group":{}},{"name":"Visitor","description":"no permissions","group":{}},
{"name":"NewRoleInGroup","description":"NewRoleInGroup description","group":{"name":"GroupA","description":"Description GroupA"}},
{"name":"admin","description":"can RW group, user","group":{"name":"GroupA","description":"Description GroupA"}},
{"name":"employee","description":"can R group, can read user","group":{"name":"GroupA","description":"Description GroupA"}}
]
```

Where should I write the count in the pipeline ( I guess after the $match ?)
 and how can I insert the count into the result ?  ( I guess after the  $sort ?)

Maybe there is no way to do it in one aggregate , and the only possibility is to perform first a collection count then the aggregate and insert the counter object before returning the result ( using Promise.all it can be done in parallel.. )

thanks for feedback

Answer (score 0):

My solution is a bit rude but I hope it will help you before finding the best solution. I use the lodash or can be native javascript. Its handle looks like this!

```
    ROLES: [
         {"name":"NewRole","description":"NewRole description","group":{}},{"name":"Visitor","description":"no permissions","group":{}},
         {"name":"NewRoleInGroup","description":"NewRoleInGroup description","group":{"name":"GroupA","description":"Description GroupA"}},
         {"name":"admin","description":"can RW group, user","group":{"name":"GroupA","description":"Description GroupA"}},
         {"name":"employee","description":"can R group, can read user","group":{"name":"GroupA","description":"Description GroupA"}},
         {"name":"manager","description":"can R group, can RW user","group":{"name":"GroupA","description":"Description GroupA"}},
         {"name":"employee","description":"can R group, can read user","group":{"name":"GroupB","description":"Description GroupB"}},
         {"name":"manager","description":"can R group, can RW user","group":{"name":"GroupB","description":"Description GroupB"}},
         {"name":"employee","description":"can R group, can read user","group":{"name":"GroupC","description":"Description GroupC"}}
    ];
    ROLES.unshift({"roleCount": ROLES.length})
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback ... this should work  BUT in my case I need to count the matching documents before the $limit/$skip in the aggregate, otherwise the final output ROLES.length will be equal to the $limit... Am I clear enough ?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is actually to perform it in 2 steps , first counting , then aggregation with limit/skip. These 2 steps can be run in parallel as Promises with Promise.all, then returning both results ( count and data )

```
  list(query, pageNumber, resultsPerPage, skipDocuments, sortBy) {

    const counting = this.count()
      .then((count) => {
        return {"roles": count};
      })
      .catch((e) => { throw(e); });
    const aggregation = this.aggregate([
      { $lookup: { from: 'groups', localField: '_group', foreignField: '_id', as: 'group'} },
      { $match: query },
      { $project: { group: { $let:{ vars:{ firstGroup:{ $arrayElemAt:["$group",0] } },  in:{ name:"$$firstGroup.name", description:"$$firstGroup.description" } } }, name: 1, description: 1, _id: 0 } },
      { $sort: sortBy },
      { $skip: skipDocuments },   // SKIP ALWAYS BEFORE LIMIT !
      { $limit: resultsPerPage }
    ]).exec()
      .then((list) => {
        return list;
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log('MongoDB Error: ', e);
        return new APIError('Cannot list roles!', httpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
      });

    return Promise.all([counting, aggregation])
      .then((values) => {
        console.log('VALUES: %j', values);
```

return values;
          })
          .catch((e) => { throw(e); });
      },

so we get exactly whats is needed :

```
  VALUES: [
  {"roles":9},
  [{"name":"NewRole","description":"NewRole description","group":{}},{
  "name":"Visitor","description":"no permissions","group":{}},
  {"name":"NewRoleInGroup","description":"NewRoleInGroup description","group":{"name":"GroupA","description":"Description GroupA"}},
  {"name":"admin","description":"can RW group, user","group":{"name":"GroupA","description":"Description GroupA"}},
  {"name":"employee","description":"can R group, can read user","group":{"name":"GroupA","description":"Description GroupA"}},
  {"name":"manager","description":"can R group, can RW user","group":{"name":"GroupA","description":"Description GroupA"}},
  {"name":"employee","description":"can R group, can read user","group":{"name":"GroupB","description":"Description GroupB"}},
  {"name":"manager","description":"can R group, can RW user","group":{"name":"GroupB","description":"Description GroupB"}},
  {"name":"employee","description":"can R group, can read user","group":{"name":"GroupC","description":"Description GroupC"}
  }]]
```